# AmazonMQ ActiveMQ Performance Improvement with C#

Tags: amazon-web-services, activemq-classic, amqp, amazon-mq, amqpnetlite

We are using AmazonMQ using ActiveMQ in an ASP.NET Core Microservice that require high throughput. My message size is around 1KB.
We are using AmqpNETLite.Core as the client library for the same. AWS has documented its Queue [benchmark](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/migration-guide/chapter-benchmarks.html) here.

[image: Amazon MQ Benchmark]

In my application, I am using only 1 producer. I tried sync `Send` and `AsyncSend` API of `SenderLink`.

Average time taken when sending 10000 messages to queue in `AsyncSend` is ~125ms and sync `Send` mode is ~25ms per message. When I tried using Transactions for 100 message batches in Sync mode, my average time reduced to ~15ms. This time taken is ~25 time poorer than the performance AWS is offering in the above benchmark for 25 producers.

I tried to use  `concurrentStoreAndDispatchQueues` as false and transactions in an effort to improve performance to AWS's benchmark.

Can someone help me identify what I am doing wrong?

1. I use only 1 producer. Does AWS imply I need 25 producers to achieve the above 1750 TPS?
2. I use `AMQP` wire level protocol. But the benchmark is on `openwire`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only 1 producer is going to artificially limit the performance as the overall throughput will be based solely on the throughput of that one producer. In order to at least attempt to get the same performance numbers you need to use the same number of producers and consumers as used in the original test (i.e. 25, 50, 100, or 200).

Also, performance *will* be different between AMQP and OpenWire simply because the protocol implementation on the broker is different.

Comment: I got a similar reply from AWS support too. So, I think my injestion rate is too high for Amazon MQ.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "injestion rate"? Do you mean the rate at which you're sending messages? If so, I'd say it's too _low_ since you're only using 1 producer. Again, concurrency will be your friend here (to a point) since more producers will be able to send more messages.

Comment: We have a technical bottleneck that holds us down from using multiple producers. So That is dead end except for a 30% use case.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you mean by "injestion rate" and also on what what you mean by "30% use case."

Comment: Injestion rate - The rate in which I want messages to be pushed to queue from one producer.

Comment: "30% use case": I could maybe use a second producer to push 30% of my messages. but the bigger load can go in a single blocking syncronous producer only.

Comment: As noted, using "a single blocking syncronous producer" is going to artificially limit performance. I wouldn't expect you to ever get to comparable throughput using this. Is there a specific reason you can't use concurrent producers?

Comment: Yes. There is a specific reason we cannot use concurrent producers. This is an integration with another system and is a design consideration to be able to handle my traffic using one producer.

Comment: My research and one of your own SO answers directed me to SoftwareMill's queue perf comparison. Which got me interested in ActiveMQ Artemis ~30 times faster than ActiveMQ. Wonder why AWS does not have a managed version of Artemis in Amazon MQ broker options

Comment: My _feeling_ is that Amazon is employing a specific strategy aimed at migrating legacy, on-premise deployments of ActiveMQ "Classic" onto the cloud. Given that it has been the de facto Open Source JMS broker since 2007 I'm sure there are many such deployments employing basic JMS use-cases with relatively low throughput. Asking organizations to move to the cloud *and* to change brokers is a much higher risk for them no matter what the alternative broker might be. Getting these organizations to move *any* workload onto their platform is a great way to upsell and cross-sell them as well.